# Recursion issues when solving Sudoku puzzles

Tags: python, recursion, sudoku

I'm trying to write a program to solve a Sudoku puzzle. I have a dictionary that holds all empty cell position as keys and their respective possible values in a list. Shown below is a part of the dictionary

```
empty_cells = {'00': ['3', '5', '6'], '01': ['1', '3', '5'], '06': ['1', '6']}
```

I'm trying to recursively call a function to brute force through this list but I can't seem to progress through the list.

```
def brute(board):
    for cell in list(empty_cells):
        for n in empty_cells[cell]:

            board[int(cell[0])][int(cell[1])] = n

            brute(board)

            board[int(cell[0])][int(cell[1])] = "."   
        
        return
```

I'm not really sure why whenever I call the `brute` function, the function does not move on to the next empty cell in the list and just stays at the 00 cell till the recursive depth is reached.

Comment: You call `brute`, for the first empty cell, you call `brute` again, for the first empty cell, you call `brute` again, for the first empty cell, you call `brute`... Have you tried to use a debugger to understand the program flow?

Comment: I do understand that every time I call the function it starts at the first empty cell what I don't understand is why because every single video/tutorial that I have seen so far follows essentially the same program flow like this video here from [Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM&ab_channel=Computerphile)

Comment: Recursive functions need a _base case_, i.e. some condition for which they do _not_ recursively call themselves again, but instead simply return some value.  Your function does not have this.  It _always_ calls itself again, endlessly.

Comment: @Sidd In the video you have linked, the _global_ state on which the `solve` method works (`grid` in that case) changes between the recursive calls. In your case, you change `board`, but your `brute` does always the same, no matter what the content of `board` is. `brute`'s behavior is only dependent on `empty_cells` which never changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have no way of keeping track of your progress. If you think about it thoroughly, you are forever calling brute, arriving at key "00", at option '3', setting board[int(cell[0])][int(cell[1])] to '3', and repeating, setting board[int(cell[0])][int(cell[1])] to '3' again in the next recursion, and again and again.

To fix this implement some way to keep track of the current state. I suggest instead of iterating through all possibilities you make a function that finds the next open cell. And of course, your code needs some kind of condition to check if you have won or not

Answer (score -2):

I think it iterates ok, but you are assigning to something else

try changing

```
board[int(cell[0])][int(cell[1])]
```

to

```
board[int(key[0])][int(key[1])]
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why but it still doesn't seem to work. The assigning in my actual code was correct I just made a typo when asking the question because I was trying to change the variables to make the question clearer